# Seeing this error on my intellij and I am also having issue importing WebDriverWait and dependecies is already in POM.XML

Tags: selenium, testing, ui-automation

This is for WebDriverWait issue

[image]

I am unable to import it despite the dependeny in my pom file.

This is for the error I am seeing my Intellij. it is like there is an issue with maven repo

[image]

```
package atda;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LoginPage {
    private final WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver();
    }

    public void open() {
        driver.get("suacedemo.com");
    }

    public boolean isLoaded() {
        WebDriverWait
    }
}
```

I was hoping to be able to add WebDriverWait from Maven dependencies but it is not available despite the dependency has been added to POM

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the IDE to automatically import WebDriverWait you will need to complete the line of code. For example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```

If not then WebDriverWait can be imported from:

`import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;`

In addition, ensure that you have copied your selenium dependency from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I really appreciate it.  I have tried to import the WebDriverWait but I could not and I when I tried to add maven dependency through the WebDriverWait code it says "No results" Try updating Maven Indexes. So, I clicked on the link and it directed me to Repositories and it shows error. I I will add the screenshots here.

Comment: Alright it seems your issue is with the maven repo which could be for several reason so these solutions may or may not work for you. For example, whether or not you are using a proxy could affect this as well.
Either way try disabling File -> Settings -> Maven -> Importing -> "Use maven3 to import project."
This [thread](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102693) goes over this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the screenshots as I could not add them in the comments. I have attached them in their order according to the explanation in the comment. I would appreciate it if I could be assisted.

This is the screenshot of the WebDriverWait in the code:
[image: This is the screenshot of the WebDriverWait in the code]

This shows the error message:
[image: This shows the error message]

This shows where it says No results when I tried to add Maven Dependeny:
[image: This shows where it says No results when I tried to add Maven Dependeny]

This shows error in the remote repositories
[image: This shows error in the remote repositories]

Thank you for your help!